# После перезагрузки сервера не стартует nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, администрирование, centos

После установки на CentOS 7 nginx'а командой `yum install nginx` я ввел команду `systemctl enable nginx.service`, которая выдала:

```
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.
```

Но после перезагрузки сервера, nginx не запускается автоматически и приходится запускать его командой `systemctl start nginx.service`.

Почему так происходит? И как заставить nginx запускаться автоматически после перезагрузки сервера?

Comment: а в логах нет подсказок? так как он должен стартовать.

Comment: Created symlink  выдает после установки сервиса. а не автозапуска

Comment: вывод `systemctl  status nginx ` приложите к вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Доброго! В нете указана такая команда: **systemctl enable nginx** для CenOS7.
В отношении 6-го указывалась такая **chkconfig --levels 235 nginx on** (указывает уровни запуска системы при которых производится автозапуск nginx) или **chkconfig nginx on** - возможно, и они сработают

Comment: `возможно`?  а возможно нет ?

Comment: у меня и в RFR24 и CentOS6 срабатывала именно chkconfig nginx on . Или подобие для других прог: chkconfig mysqld on